# How to include an Image URL from Firebase Storage that is being blocked by cors, as part of a PDF file

Tags: vuejs3, pdf-generation, firebase-storage, jspdf, html2canvas

I have  component that renders an invoice part of the html includes an image that the src is a url from Firebase Storage. I am using jspdf & html2canvas to create a pdf file.

The image renders fine in Vue component but does not render in pdf created with jspdf & html2 canvas.

I suspect the image is not being allowed because of cors issues.

Trying to figure a way to show the image in the pdf file. I see in html2canvas docs you need to use a proxy not sure how to do this in my app or if it is necessary.

EDIT
My application is deployed on Netlify, so not sure if running an express server would be practical. In the end just trying to download a pdf from the generated html that includes a dynamic image in my Vue component.

Here is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/invoice-to-pdf-vzd7gw)

Notice the image 200 x 200 shown in demo is not in the pdf

Note the image src url can change is not meant to be hard coded.

Here is my HTML

```
<template>
  <div ref="invoiceContent">
    <div>
      <AppAvatarImage :src="invoice.avatar" />
    </div>
  </div>
  ..... other stuff that renders fine
</template>
```

Here is my method to save pdf file.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
const invoiceContent = ref(null);

const props = defineProps({
  invoice: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});

const savePdf = () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'p',
    unit: 'px',
    format: 'legal',
    hotfixes: ['px_scaling'],
  });

  html2canvas(invoiceContent.value, {
    width: doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(),
    height: doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight(),
  }).then((canvas) => {
    const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
    if (screen.width < 700) {
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 50, 50, screen.width * 3, doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight());
    } else {
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 150, 50, doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(), doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight());
    }

    doc.save('Invoice.pdf');
  });
};
</script>
```

Here is my method to get image url from Firebase Storage.

```
async uploadAvatar({ file }) {
      if (!file) return null;
      let filename = file.name;
      try {
        const storeAuth = useStoreAuth();
        let name = `${Date.now()}-${filename}`;
        let path = `uploads/${storeAuth.user.id}/profileImgs/${name}`;
        const storageRef = ref(storage, path);

        await uploadBytes(storageRef, file);

        const avatarURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

        let data = {
          id: storeAuth.user.id,
          avatar: avatarURL,
        };

        await this.updateUserAvatar(data);

        return avatarURL;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('File Upload Error');
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
```

My AppAvatarImage component.

```
<template>
  <img :src="src || profileImg" />
</template>
<script setup>
import profileImg from '@/assets/images/all-img/user.svg';

const props = defineProps({
  src: {
    type: String,
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure CORS for Firebase Cloud Storage to allow your frontend URL access.

1. Download the `gsutil` CLI.  [Download link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install)
2. Create a file `cors.json` with the following data:

```json
[
  {
    "origin": ["https://example.netlify.app"], // ["*"] to allow all origins
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

3. Run the command `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>`

It should now work.  All of the above information can also be found in the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm having a hard time getting up and running with gsutil  as I only have basic command line skills. I did download gsutil to my local machine not sure of rest of set up does this need to be added to path etc. Or would google cloud terminal be easier. I assume the cors.json file goes in my project?

Comment: I figured it out used cloud shell terminal and uploaded my cors.json file to the terminal

Comment: The image is still not showing after cors set maybe it's a chaching thing will wait and test later. Note the height and width is being set just no image.

Comment: I accepted this answer as I was able to set cors on the storage bucket. But this did not solve the problem. The image does not render in pdf but does render in Vue component. Same result as in the demo codeSandbox posted here in the question

Answer (score -1):

The CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue you're encountering is because the image you are trying to load in the PDF from Firebase Storage has a different origin than your application's domain. you can use a proxy server to fetch the image and serve it to your application.

Create a Node.js server to act as a proxy for fetching images from Firebase Storage. You can use a library like express for this purpose

```
npm install express
```

Create a new Node.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
    
app.get('/proxy-image', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const imageUrl = req.query.url;
    const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
    
    if (response.ok) {
      const imageBuffer = await response.buffer();
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', response.headers.get('content-type'));
      res.send(imageBuffer);
    } else {
      res.status(response.status).send('Failed to fetch image');
    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Proxy error:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Proxy error');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Image proxy server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Start the proxy server by running

```
node imageProxy.js
```

Update your Vue component to use the proxy server to fetch images. Modify the AppAvatarImage component to use the /proxy-image route to fetch the image. updated version of your AppAvatarImage component

```html
<template>
  <img :src="imageSrc || profileImg" />
</template>
        
<script setup>
  import profileImg from '@/assets/images/all-img/user.svg';
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
        
  const props = defineProps({
    src: {
      type: String,
    },
  });
        
  const imageSrc = ref(props.src);
        
  onMounted(() => {
    if (props.src && !props.src.startsWith('data:')) {
    // If the source is not a data URI, fetch it through the proxy
    imageSrc.value = `/proxy-image?url=${encodeURIComponent(props.src)}`;
    }
  });
</script>
```